# MessageBox.Show format

Tags: c#

I just started learning C# so bear with me.  I have been looking everywhere for help on this simple issue.

I have program that requires the user to guess a random number and after the number is guessed a message box appears that says your correct and how many guesses it took.  I just moved from creating console apps to windows form apps and have painfully realized that its a different set of rules.

```
MessageBox.Show("You are right! It took you " +totalGuesses," guesses",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

I need the output to say that  You are right! It took you 9 guesses.

what I end up getting is **You are right! It took you 9** and **guesses** is the title of the messagebox.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please.

Comment: Hi @Monti, welcome to StackOverflow. If one of the answers has helped resolve your question, would you mind 'accepting' it by clicking on the check mark next to the question? That way, (a) others will know that you're satisfied and (b) both you and the answerer will gain some reputation on StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 4):

This would be the correct method call:

```
MessageBox.Show("You are right! It took you " + totalGuesses + " guesses","Title of your Box",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

In c# methods could have different parameters, each seperated with ",". Methods could also be overloaded so that you can call the same method but with different parameters:
So if you just want to display a message in a MessageBox you could write:

```
MessageBox.Show("Your Message");
```

If you want to add a title to your Message:

```
MessageBox.Show("Your Message", "Title");
```

IntelliSense is a good help for you in this case as it should show a short discription of the parameter each time you insert a "," in the method call.

In your case you put a "," in front of "guesses". The result is, that c# sees it as the second parameter which is the title of the box.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally recommended to use String.Format for these types of things.  Try the following:

```
var message = string.Format("You are right! It took you {0} guesses.", guesses);
MessageBox.Show(message, "Correct!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well like;

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You are right! It took you {0} guesses", totalGuesses), 
                "Caption",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Nope, I am just too stupid. There is no such an overload and I always forget it. Fixed with `(String, String, MessageBoxButtons)` solution. Thank you.